# LIKE not working in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, matching, sql-like

Consider this [TSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL):

```
declare @b varchar(100)

set @b = 'BANK-41'

IF @b LIKE 'BANK_%'
BEGIN
    print 'Wrong Matching'
END
```

Why does the TSQL match the string "`BANK-`" and "`BANK_`"?

Answer (score 7):

In TSQL the underscore is a wildcard representing a single char.

In order to escape in you need to wrap it with square brackets, like this:

'BANK[_]%'

See this page:
http://www.dirigodev.com/blog/web-development-execution/escaping-percent-and-underscore-characters-in-t-sql-like-clause/

Answer (score 3):

An underscore in SQL Server is reserved for a wild card character, I think.  You need to escape it.I think you can put it in brackets:

```
%[_]%
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It was great help to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the "_". It is a special character for the Like statement. You can enclose it in [].

See *[LIKE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)*.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It was great help to understand this.